# How to store NSMutableArray of user defined class objects to file system in iphone?

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults

Can anyone please tell me how to write NSMutableArray of custom class objects to file?
below is the code which i am using to write my array "medicationsArray" to file.
medicationsArray contains the objects of below medicationData class

@interface medicationData: NSObject {
    NSString *drName;
    NSString *date;
    NSString *description;
}
@end

```
NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentDir = [path objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *pathWithFileName;

NSString *pathWithFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/medicationsArray",documentDir];
[medicationsArray writeToFile:pathWithFileName atomically:NO];
```

by using this code i am not able to create a file.
can anyone help me in this, thanks in advance

Comment: So, your medicationsArray contains medicationData, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of constructing the pathWithFileName "manually" you should use the stringByAppendingPathComponent: method instead:

```
NSString *pathWithFileName = [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"medicationsArray"];
```

This will take care of any extra slashes, etc. in the path. This might be the reason your path may be wrong. I presume that the extra declaration of `pathWithFileName` in your snippet is just a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the reply Claus,
Now i am able to store the data, i am using NSArchiver and NSUnArchiver.
below is the code please find.

```
NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentDir = [path objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *pathWithFileName;

pathWithFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/medicationsArray",documentDir];
NSData *savedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:appDelegate.medicationsArray];
[savedData writeToFile:pathWithFileName atomically:YES];
```

to extract the data

```
if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:pathWithFileName])
{
    NSData *savedData = [[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pathWithFileName] retain];
    appDelegate.medicationsArray = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:savedData] retain];
    [objMedicationDetailsTVController.tableView reloadData];
}
```